# Adjust <img> height according to the window height - Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, viewport

I have a code:

```
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
     <div style="height: 80%;">
      <img src="..." alt"...">
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

I want to set the image height according to the window height. I've set html and body height to 100% and it works alright. However, as I understand, in order to properly set the image height to 80% I need to set the container, row and col-md-12 height to 100% too. Here I face a problem - their height remains `auto` for some reason.

Are there any other ways to set the image height to 80% of the window?

Answer (score 0):

most of height definitions only work with `position: absolute;` Definitions of other elements refering to the parent height are usually ignored.